# How to Capture all groups with a dot followed by a space NOT preceeded by two given strings in Google sheets Regex?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, regex-negation

I could not find a duplicate question.

I need to capture groups of `period` followed by `a space`.
But only those groups than are not preceeded by those two strings:
`Zn` and `Zns`.

I tested this:

```
[^Z][^n](\.\s)
```

https://regex101.com/r/ARZxAV/1

And this:

```
([^Z][^n]|[^Z][^n][^s])(\.\s)
```

https://regex101.com/r/cvEUKM/1

And this:

```
(?!Zn)(\.\s)
```

https://regex101.com/r/IUZeso/1

On this sample:

```
1) aaa. Zn. bbb
2) aaa. Zn. bbb.
3) aaa Zn. bbb.
4) aaa Zn. bbb
5) aaa Bns. bbb
6) aaa Bns. Bbb
7) aaa Zn. Aaa Bns. Bbb
8) 1
9) aaa
10) aaa.
11) aaa Abbb
12) aaa. Zns. bbb
13) aaa. Zns. bbb.
14) aaa Zns. bbb.
15) aaa Zns. bbb
```

How to capture only the `a.`  , `b.`  and `s.`  (of the `aaa.`  `bbb.`  `Bns.`  groups in the sample) groups from the sample above, excluding the `Zn.`  and `Zns.`  ?

Expected output from sample in bold:

1. **aaa.** Zn. bbb
2. **aaa.** Zn. **bbb.**
3. aaa Zn. **bbb.**
4. aaa Zn. bbb
5. aaa **Bns.** bbb
6. aaa **Bns.** Bbb
7. aaa Zn. Aaa **Bns.** Bbb
8. 1
9. aaa
10. **aaa.**
11. aaa Abbb
12. **aaa.** Zns. bbb
13. **aaa.** Zns. **bbb.**
14. aaa Zns. **bbb.**
15. aaa Zns. bbb

Answer (score 1):

*`non-regex` formula for **`Sheets`**:*

```js
=let(Σ,split(A2," "),
 ifna(filter(Σ,right(Σ)=".",iserror(xmatch(Σ,{"Zn.","Zns."})))))
```

- *Use `join()` if you want all the output groups accommodated in single cell*

[image]

***arrayformula style***:

```js
=map(A2:A,lambda(Λ,if(Λ="",,let(Σ,split(Λ," "),join(" ",ifna(filter(Σ,right(Σ)=".",iserror(xmatch(Σ,{"Zn.","Zns."})))))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @rockingfreakshow. It works great for my larger use which was to check for it and ignore it with this : `=if(TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,let(Σ,split(B10," "),
 ifna(filter(Σ,right(Σ)=".",iserror(xmatch(Σ,{"Zn.","Zns."}))))))<>"",B10,"")` .  Any way to modify if to use with the arrayformula? I tested this one but got the "FILTER range must be a single row or a single column." Error 
 : `=ArrayFormula(if(TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,let(Σ,split(B12:B," "),
 ifna(filter(Σ,right(Σ)=".",iserror(xmatch(Σ,{"Zn.","Zns."}))))))<>"",B12:B,""))`

Comment: Because the solution is not directly related to the regex, I'll wait to see if a regex specific answer is provided and if not will accept it, or will create a 2nd question similar but for `filter`.

Comment: Updated the `arrayformula` style solution in the answer section.

Comment: Thanks again! Works great, also to the reverse effect with the arrayformula I added as this: `=ArrayFormula(
if(
map(B10:B,lambda(Λ,if(Λ="",,let(Σ,split(Λ," "),join(" ",ifna(filter(Σ,right(Σ)=".",iserror(xmatch(Σ,{"Zn.","Zns."})))))))))<>"",
B10:B,""))` Thank again! Be well!

Answer (score 1):

You might use a regex with a custom function.

```
\b(?!Zns?\b)[a-zA-Z]+\.\s
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `(?!Zns?\b)` Negative lookahead, assert not `Zn` or `Zns` directly to the right
- `[a-zA-Z]+` match 1+ chars a-zA-Z
- `\.\s` Match `.` and a whitspace char (which could also match a newline)

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TDVscU/1).

For example:

```
function myFunction(input) {
    const regex = /\b(?!Zns?\b)[a-zA-Z]+\.\s/g;
    const res = Array.from(input.matchAll(regex), m => m[0]);
    return res.length ? [res] : [[""]];
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks @The fourth bird. That is an interesting solution as I did not know how to create an apps script function with regex. It works, but too bad the same regex can't be used within google sheets formulas. Is there some way to modify it for use with a formula for easier maniuplation with other functions? I tried this `=regexextract(C36,"\s(?!Zns\s)[a-zA-Z]+\.\s")` but ti return this error: `Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 2 value "\s(?!Zns\s)[a-zA-Z]+\.\s" is not a valid regular expression.`  If not that's ok. Thanks again!

Comment: @Lod Using it with a formula is not possible with this pattern, as the regex engine used there is `re2` which does not support lookarounds.

Comment: Ok thanks for that precision that helps. Thanks for the help! Be well!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A15,"Zns?\.|([A-Za-z]+\.)|.","$1 ")," "))
```

Comment: Thanks @z" for the alternative. I tested and it does work as per the expected output. Screenshot here:  https://i.imgur.com/qx4DHhz.png